# How to write small size text between the itemised?

Tags: itemize

I want to write between the itemise, that is after one bullet point, I want to add 2 small sentences below it. See my code and what I want is given below:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
 \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
 \usepackage{xcolor}

 \begin{document}
 \section{\textcolor{blue}{Testing Nilpotence in linear time}}
 Given a group $G$ in the form of mutiplication table, we want to check to decide  divides the order of $G$}. Algorithm for testing nilpotence is given below. \\

 \begin{itemize}
 \item Compute the prime factorization of $n= p_1^{\alpha_1} \times p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_i^{\alpha_i}$. \\
 \item Determine the order of all elements in $G$. \\
 \item For $1 \le i \le r$, check if $\mathcal{N}(p_i^{\alpha_i}) \neq p_i^{\alpha_i}$ then $G$ is not nilpotent. \\
\item Else output that $G$ is nilpotent  
 \end{itemize}
```

see compiled output :
[image]

Question : How to add small text as given in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you create a little utility macro called `\aside`. If `\footnotesize` makes the text too small for your taste, use `\small` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\aside[1]{\par\quad{\footnotesize(#1)}\par} % or "\small", if you prefer

\begin{document}
\section{\color{blue}Testing Nilpotence in linear time}

Given a group $G$ in the form of multiplication table, we want to check to 
decide [...] divides the order of $G$. An algorithm for testing nilpotence 
is given below.

\begin{itemize}
\item Compute the prime factorization of $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} \times 
     p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots \times p_i^{\alpha_i}$.
     \aside{Each $p_i^{\alpha_i}$ is the highest power}

\item Determine the order of all elements in $G$. 
     \aside{It can be done easily}

\item For $1 \le i \le r$, check if $\mathcal{N}(p_i^{\alpha_i}) \neq 
     p_i^{\alpha_i}$. If true, $G$ is not nilpotent.

\item Else, conclude that $G$ is nilpotent.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

- your mwe is not complete (missing is `\end{document}`)
- it also contain error (superfluous `}` after  `$G$`)
- all `\\` after items are superfluous
- additional line below (main) item just write in new line (you can select smaller font size for this line(s) )
- for better formatting use package `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section{\textcolor{blue}{Testing Nilpotence in linear time}}
Given a group $G$ in the form of multiplication table, we want to check to decide  divides the order of $G$. Algorithm for testing nilpotence is given below. %\\ had to be removed

\begin{itemize}[itemsep=1ex,leftmargin=1cm]
\item Compute the prime factorization of $n= p_1^{\alpha_1} \times p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_i^{\alpha_i}$.               % "\\" had to be removed

    {\small(small text in the next line)}
\item Determine the order of all elements in $G$. % "\\" had to be removed

    {\small(small text in the next line)}
\item For $1 \le i \le r$, check if $\mathcal{N}(p_i^{\alpha_i}) \neq p_i^{\alpha_i}$ then $G$ is not nilpotent.            % "\\" had to be removed

    {\small(small text in the next line)}
\item Else output that $G$ is nilpotent
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]